# Java method algorithm fix

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, methods

The method is simple, it takes in a string name, a array and a int. The method takes in the string and add it to the array in alphabetical order.  The `int x` is the current count of how many elements are already inside the array(partially filled). Now, if the string gets added it returns true. If not and the array is full then it return false. how do i fix this?

Code:

```java
public static String add(String name, String[] list, int x) {
    String[] updatedArray = new String[x + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        updatedArray[i] = list[i];
    }
    updatedArray[x] = name;
    Arrays.sort(updatedArray);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to check if `x` is beyond the size of the array?

Comment: yes. and i am also asking how i can returen true if the item is added and false if the array is full and can't be added.

Answer (score 0):

Doing

```
String[] updatedArray = new String[x + 1];
for(int i =0; i<x; i++){
    updatedArray[i] = list[i];
}
```

you basically create a new array with one more index (empty), so it will always be possible to add the `name` element